# Santa Claus, its dwarf and its reindeer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following class.

The aim is to have a few methods that deal with the type of the gift, the dwarf who is packing the gifts and the time he will take. And finally, the reindeer, which is supposed to do the work.

```
class kdo_pack():

    def __init__(self, maxsledge = 12, remainingplace=0):
        self.maxsledge = maxsledge
        self.remainingplace = remainingplace
        self.giftlist = []

    def gift_type(self,size_gift):
        if size_gift == 1:
            return "half second"
        elif size_gift == 2:
            return "one second"
        elif size_gift == 5:
            return "2 seconds"  

    def Dwarf(self):
        while self.remainingplace < self.maxsledge:
            self.size_gift = int(input("type the size, 1 (for 1kg),2 (for 2kg) or 5 (for 5 kg) \n"))

            temps = self.gift_type(self.size_gift)
            print('It will take me ',temps, ' because the size of the gift is  {} kg'.format(self.size_gift))

            self.remainingplace += self.size_gift
            #return self.remainingplace
            self.giftlist.append(self.size_gift)
            #print(self.remainingplace)
            #print(self.giftlist)


    def Reindeer(self):
        print("list of gift is the following : ",self.giftlist)     
        self.printcounter = len(self.giftlist)
        #print(self.printcounter)
        #print(len(self.giftlist))

        while self.printcounter > 0:            
            if self.printcounter %5 == 0:
                print(self.printcounter)
                print("I stop, give me reindeer milk !")
                break
            else:
                self.giftlist.remove(self.giftlist[0])  
                self.printcounter-=1
                print("there are only {} gifts to deliver".format(self.printcounter))





vari_xmas = kdo_pack()
vari_xmas.Dwarf()
vari_xmas.Reindeer()
```

Code is working fine. However, I'm bit bugged by a few things:

- I'm using often a `while` loop for two of the methods. Although it is doing the job, it doesn't feel pythonic.
- There is this `if self.printcounter %5 == 0:` in the method `Reindeer`. The aim is to mimic the following

  > One time over 5, when the reindeer is asked to move, it refuses because it want reindeer milk… The only way is to ask it again and it will go.

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but what is it you want this code to do?  It doesn't feel like it should be a class at all, but rather a function with nested helper functions -- it's not representing an object, it's representing a process.

Comment: hi @SamStafford I took it from a kata. There is no guideline if I should use a class or function with nested helper functions. I use class because it seems coherent, at least to me. But if you have another way to do that, I'm all ears. Tbh, it is often difficult to say what should be the norm and what is not as there are no real guidelines (I could not find any in this situation). I end up often writing something and some ppl say "well it is not the norm!".

Comment: omg ... why the downvote ... T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of this code:

```
from typing import Dict, List

def kdo_pack():
    gifts: List[int] = []
    gift_time: Dict[int, str] = {
        1: "half second",
        2: "one second",
        5: "2 seconds",
    }
    sled_capacity = 12

    # Pack the gifts onto the sled!
    while sum(gifts) < sled_capacity:
        try:
            gift = int(input(
                "type the size, 1 (for 1kg),2 (for 2kg) or 5 (for 5 kg) \n"
            ))
            print(
                'It will take me {} because the size of the gift is  {} kg'
                    .format(gift_time[gift], gift)
            )
        except (KeyError, ValueError):
            break
        gifts.append(gift)

    # Deliver the gifts!
    print("list of gift is the following : ", gifts)
    while gifts:
        if len(gifts) % 5 == 0:
            print(len(gifts))
            print("I stop, give me reindeer milk !")
            break
        gifts.pop()
        print("there are only {} gifts to deliver".format(len(gifts)))

kdo_pack()
```

It's not completely clear to me how the class is meant to be used, but in the context of the script you've given I don't think it needs to be a class at all; you're just doing a fixed sequence of steps and there's no result other than what gets printed to the console.

Since the program would halt prematurely if the user inputted an invalid value, I modified it to break and move on to the next step instead since that makes it easier to test without having to fill the entire sled.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what else to suggest since I'm not sure what the original intent was, but hopefully seeing the simplified code gets you thinking about ways to streamline your future efforts -- the rule of thumb is not to write code that you don't need to.  :)